# WINDOWS : How can I get NVM to work on multiple integrated terminals in VS Code at once?

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, visual-studio-code, nvm

I recently install NVM for Windows following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows

Overall, things work when using an external GitBash terminal and/or using GitBash in the VS Code integrated terminal. BUT if I open another Angular project in VS Code I am noticing an issue when I try to run commands in a second integrated terminal. No commands can be found, both Node and Ng commands.

Any ideas on why? Sometimes I need to run multiple projects at one time, so having two integrated terminals open and running those projects is helpful.

Also, when I restart my computer, the one project that wasn't working works fine. It's always the second project integrated terminal that doesn't work.

[image: Picture of terminals (2 integrated, 1 external)]

I've tried restarting my computer multiple times. I've tried to figure out if it was a certain project that wasn't working. I've searched for a little, but most solutions are Mac focused

Also, I've checked that my Bash path's are the same in my terminal v. my Vs Code terminal settings:

[image: Terminal Path Settings]

Update: I am also finding, once this happens and I close both VS Codes and open any Angular project in VS Code, my VS Code terminals stop working no matter what.

My external terminal continues to work fine.

Here is what my $PATH looks like when things are working:

[Working $PATH External Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi62o.png)

[Working $PATH Integrated VS Code Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQGGB.png)

Here is what my $PATH looks like when things aren't working:

[Broken $PATH Integrated VS Code Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqs4F.png)

Comment: any difference in the `PATH` environment variables of the environments?

Comment: I don't think so. I added a picture in the original post to help clarify. Let me know if I am misunderstanding

Comment: uhh I don't get it. how does the screenshot show the value of the `PATH` environment variable? Ex. in Git Bash, do `echo $PATH` and paste us the output into your question post.

Comment: So I think the issue may be resolved? I am not 100% sure, but after commenting out my VS Code integrated terminal settings and un-commenting them, the issue isn't coming up any more. 

Weird. I did check the $PATH, with the command you suggested and they both were the same. 

So I am unsure why I can't replicate the issue all of sudden

Comment: I spoke too soon, it's not working again. I updated my question above with screen shots of my $PATH

Comment: please don't use screenshots for the `PATH`. It's text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541. Please fix it and change it to use _inline_ code blocks. [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the feedback. I appreciate it. I made the changes

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I solved the problem. For some reason, once I opened up another VS Code instance, my $PATH variables/directory locations were no longer found, especially for these two items

```
%NVM_HOME%:
%NVM_SYMLINK%:
```

Here is what I mean:

Here the PATH is fine:

```
/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/{user}/bin:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot/bin:
/c/Program Files/Eclipse Foundation/jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot/bin:
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:
/c/WINDOWS/system32:
/c/WINDOWS:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:
/c/Program Files (x86)/{program}/{app}/X64:
/c/Program Files (x86)/{program}/{app}/X86:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Hyland/Web ActiveX:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Reflection:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/130/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio:
/c/Program Files/dotnet:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:
/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Plantronics/Spokes3G:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/{program}/{app}:
/c/Program Files/PuTTY:
/c/Program Files/LINQPad7:
/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/nvm:
/c/Program Files/nodejs:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:
/cmd:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:
/c/Users/{user}/.dotnet/tools
```

Here is what it $PATH looks like when it is not working:

```
/c/Users/{user}/bin:
/mingw64/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/mingw64/bin:
/usr/bin:
/c/Users/{user}/bin:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot/bin:
/c/Program Files/Eclipse Foundation/jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot/bin:
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:
/c/WINDOWS/system32:
/c/WINDOWS:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:
/c/Program Files (x86)/{program}/{app}/X64:
/c/Program Files (x86)/{program}/{app}/X86:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Hyland/Web ActiveX:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Reflection:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft 
SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/130/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio:
/c/Program Files/dotnet:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn:
/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:
/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Plantronics/Spokes3G:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Pulse Secure/TNC Client Plugin:
/c/Program Files/PuTTY:
/c/Program 
Files/LINQPad7:
/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2:
%NVM_HOME%:
%NVM_SYMLINK%:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:
/cmd:
/c/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:
/c/Users/{user}/.dotnet/tools:
/usr/bin/vendor_perl:
/usr/bin/core_perl
```

So I examined my $PATH variables more and here is what I found.

On the left is my normal user account and the right is my admin account that we use to download programs etc at work. Because I had to download everything with my admin account, it probably wrote all my $PATH variables to that account settings, and not my normal user account.

So I manually added the directory locations in my Path variables on the right side and I think the issue is resolved.

[PATH Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T10Ez.jpg)

Comment: please put those code blocks in the question post where they belong. the _question post_ is expected to contain the information necessary to provide an answer.